# Liquibase migration on startup doesnt work using Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

Following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup) documentation:

```
To automatically run Liquibase database migrations on startup, add the org.liquibase:liquibase-core to your classpath.

The master change log is by default read from db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml but can be set using liquibase.change-log. In addition to YAML, Liquibase also supports JSON, XML, and SQL change log formats.
```

I configured my application to use liquibase migrations.
I added `liquibase.change-log` property so my whole `application.properties` file looks like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1/db_name
spring.datasource.username=db_username
spring.datasource.password=super_secret_secret!123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

liquibase.change-log=db.changelog-master.xml
```

and here is my `pom.xml` with `liquibase-core`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>application_name</name>
    <description>Best app ever</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

But unfortunately nothing happens on startup. I believed that this would add the table specified in my `db.changelog-master.xml` to my database but `SHOW TABLES` prints an empty set.

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include file="classpath:liquibase/changelogs/init.xml"
             relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you are missing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in your dependencies

Comment: yep, that was it. Thanks a lot. Is there any resource that you use to track which `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies are needed because there isn't any reference in the documentation that they are required.

Comment: You can take a look at pom's in the examples in the spring-boot-samples github repository.
you may also accept the answer as correct one so that people see it's solved. ;)

Comment: Yep, examining samples on gituhb seem to be the best solution provided I will remember next time I'm bootstrapping an app that I should pay attention to those elusive `spring-boot-starters`. I couldn't accept your answer erlier due to delay required by stackoverflow.

Comment: If you use Spring Boot 2, then apart from adding this dependency you also need to change the property name to spring.liquibase.change-log

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing key
spring.liquibase.enabled: true