# Why does liquibase not start when the spring boot application starts?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, liquibase

I am trying to create a basic database structure when starting a spring boot application. I need that when starting the task :bootRun was run by liquibase.

It starts without errors, a connection to the database is created, but liquibase does not start. It does not give errors, there is no information in the log about it.

Why doesn't it start automatically with spring boot?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'spring.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.1.0.M1'
    implementation group: 'org.liquibase', name: 'liquibase-core', version: '4.12.0'
    runtimeOnly'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml
```

**src/db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - logicalFilePath: db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml
  - changeSet:
    id: create-a-structure
    author: your_liquibase_username
    changes:
      - createTable:
          tableName: app_user
          columns:
            - column:
                name: id
                type: BIGINT
                autoIncrement: true
                constraints:
                  primaryKey: true
                  nullable: false
            - column:
                name: username
                type: varchar(254)
                constraints:
                  unique: true
                  nullable: false
            - column:
                name: password
                type: varchar(64)
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
            - column:
                name: first_name
                type: varchar(50)
                  nullable: false
            - column:
                name: last_name
                type: varchar(50)
                  nullable: false
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. This solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/41960712/3999476

I have a multi module maven project, I had to move the dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

to the same module where I added the dependency for liquibase.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the spring property for the changelog file should not have the classpath reference:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=db/...
```

instead of

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/...
```

Comment: 1. I tried different configurations specifying the changeset path. none of them worked.
2. It seems to me that even if the path is specified incorrectly, I should see at least some mention of liquibase in the log, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency to your project

Answer (score -1):

Just noticed that you've put the liquibase yaml in:
`src/db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml`.
Since the specified value is:
`spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml`

Could you put the file into:
`src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-root.yaml`?

Comment: I tried. if you think it's about the location of the changeset, then why are the logs absolutely empty.

Comment: You can enable all the detail logs on liquibase and spring orm/jpa related packages.  I think it can help you find out why.